# Auto solve implicit arguments by a function in Agda?

Tags: agda

Say I have a proved lemma "obvious", which states every Type is also a Solvable.

```
obvious : ∀ {A : Type} → Solvable A
obvious = one-proof
```

And I have a lemma "trivial", which somehow requires a Type A and Solvable p (depends on A),

```
trivial : ∀ {A : Type} {p : Solvable A} → A <: Top
trivial = another-proof
```

Everytime I want to use this "trivial" lemma, I probably need to write explicitly arguments A and p

```
trivial {A} {obvious A}
```

It's rather boring to write those proof because A can be inferred, but p cannot because type -checker doesn't know my "obvious" lemma so that I need to write it again and again.

How to avoid this situation?

---

In fact I've taken two attempts:

**Attempt 1**

Drop arguments p and use with-abstraction to create immediate one.

```
trivial : ∀ {A : Type} → A <: Top
trivial {A} with obvious A 
... | branch = another-proof
```

It didn't solve my case because in reality I need to do some induction on p and then recursive call "trivial" function with sub-structures of p. Agda termination checker will complain about it.

**Attempt 2**

As suggested by Agda docs, use @tactic. But I cannot find more information on its usage, can someone illustrate on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, I was hinted by an answer via function composition

```
trivial : ∀ {A : Type} → A <: Top
trivial {A} = trivial-verbose {A} {obvious A}
   where
     trivial-verbose : ∀ {A : Type} {p : Solvable A} → A <: Top
     trivial-verbose = another-proof
```

then we can always use "trivial" without explicitly writing arguments.